# How to change osrm table query limit

Tags: c++, docker, cmd, docker-container, osrm

I use my own instance of OSRM. My current maximum table query size is the default value 100. So I want to increase the query limit of OSRMtable.

I find some people suggest using

```
--max-table-size
```

I use

```
--max-table-size=10000
```

but it shows "/bin/sh: 19: --max-table-size=10000: not found".

I use

```
osrm-routed --max-table-size=10000
```

but it didn't change anything.

Someone suggests using

```
osrm-routed --max-table-size=1000 map.osrm
```

(see here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178669/how-can-i-increase-limits-of-osrm-table-function).

I tried

```
osrm-routed --max-table-size=100000 berlin-latest.osrm
```

But it shows:

> [error] Required files are missing, cannot continue

I'm not familiar with the Docker syntax. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. In the docker container Terminal, input:

```
osrm-routed --algorithm mld --max-table-size 100000000 /data/berlin-latest.osrm
```